# invalid geometry type modifier

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a postgis database on windows, postgis version "2.3.2".
When I try to re-create it on my Ubuntu server (postgis version "2.3.1") I get that error for my geometry column?

```
geom geometry(553728),
```

error:

```
ERROR:  Invalid geometry type modifier: 553728
LINE 7:     geom geometry(553728),
```

Is it related to the different versions or have I missed a step somewhere perhaps?

Regards

Comment: Probably a better fit for [gis.se] or [dba.se] if you want to flag for migration the ops will take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have SRID 553728 installed?

I've never heard of an SRID more than 5 digits so that looks suspicious and the higher ones are usually, afaik, proprietary ESRI things.

Comment: Thanks, I started this project almost a year a go and to be honest now I hardly remember what I did and not. Isn't srid in postgis / postgis_topology extensions?

Comment: Consider dumping it from the other system to this one.

Comment: yep, since it's working on that one.. i thought I should try to understand what I did though ;)

Comment: That book is amazing. =) Regina Obe for prez.